# CountDownTimer wont let me call onDestroy

Tags: android, sdk, ondestroy, countdowntimer

I have made and simple countdown timer app, but when i try to make onDestroy to cancel countdown timer i get and error. 
My onDestroy codeblock:

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
    super.onDestroy();
    countdowntimer.cancel();
    }
```

And LogCat error

```
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy        activity {com.android.SquirellMusic/com.android.SquirellMusic.SquirellMusicActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3106)
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3171)
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:132)
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1071)
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512):    at      android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512):    at com.android.SquirellMusic.SquirellMusicActivity.onDestroy(SquirellMusicActivity.java:364)
12-18 19:16:06.383: E/AndroidRuntime(25512):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3088)
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the following concept of onDestroy() of the activity :

- onDestroy() is called automatically by the DVM. After this, activity
  will be removed from the stack.

Now, your code for countdowntimer.cancel is written after the super(), so the activity (alongwith your countdowntimer object) is getting removed from the memory before your countdowntimer.cancel.

So just moving your super.onDestroy() at the end of the onDestroy() method will avoid app crashing.

Comment: i tried it and still got the same error. Is there any other possibility to cancel countdown timer when app quits?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be to save the current time and stop the timer in onPause, then restart the timer in onResume, adding to it the saved time. [for paused state]
To make sure that at the launch of app the timer starts from the begining, just assign the saved time varible 0 on onStop() [for start case]

Comment: I am a little bit confused, could you please write an example?